# Multiple Busy indicators are better? or Single busy indicator per card is better?

Tags: loading, card-views, lazy-loading

I have 3 separate async backend calls each one for the card shown below.

Is it better to have busy indicator for each card? or as shown below is a better approach?

[image]

Comment: Are those backend calls some requests a server is fulfilling and each line has its own resource loading percentage? Like file uploads?

Comment: yeah, those are backend calls.(3 calls in total, one per card).

Answer (score 2):

As discussed above if your content is arriving at one time for a particular card, and it's not on field level - it's better you have only one busy indicator for a card because all fields inside the card will become ready at the same time.